# DelegatingFilterProxy filter is not found and invoked

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-bean

This is a snippet from my web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


ERROR - SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named                                      'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
```

NO IDEA - why it is not getting invoked.

Comment: Can you provide the entire web.xml you are using, along with the Spring configuration files you are including?

Comment: Can you please share your email id, I guess it would be difficult to share on stack overflow. Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be better putting it in pastebin in order for other users to able to view it as well

Answer (score 0):

```
WEB.XML -     

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/login-security.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/login-servlet.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/login-service.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


LOGIN-SECURITY.xml

<beans:import resource="login-service.xml"/>
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/home*'
            access='ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN' />
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/admin*'
            access='ROLE_ADMIN' />
        <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsp'
            default-target-url='/home' authentication-failure-url='/login.jsp?error=true' />
        <security:logout logout-success-url='/login.jsp' />
        <security:anonymous username='guest'
            granted-authority='ROLE_GUEST' />
        <security:remember-me />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>

            <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref='myDataSource'
                users-by-username-query="select username, password, 'true' as enabled from USER_DETAILS where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select USER_DETAILS.username , USER_AUTH.AUTHORITY as authorities from USER_DETAILS,USER_AUTH 
               where USER_DETAILS.username = ? AND USER_DETAILS.username=USER_AUTH.USERNAME"></security:jdbc-user-service>

        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


LOGIN-SERVICE.xml

    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
            <beans:property name="username" value="system" />
            <beans:property name="password" value="oracle" />



LOGIN-SERVLET.xml

<context:component-scan base-package="com.poc.security" />

    <bean id="internalResourceResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <bean
        class='org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter' />
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be that you need to add commas between the xml file locations of .
Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12125135/2504224) answer for more details

Comment: Did not work that way either. I followed [link]http://www.baeldung.com/no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined