# SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to write spring application, and I have this code, but when run this code using Tomcat 8, This error appeared,  I don't know what is the root cause of error, please help

Error:

```
  01:15:02.681 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
01:15:02.756 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment
01:15:02.756 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.757 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.761 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.762 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.764 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.764 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
01:15:02.766 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Jun 20 01:15:02 AST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
01:15:02.769 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
01:15:02.802 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
01:15:02.803 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.803 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.803 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
01:15:02.822 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initializing new StandardEnvironment
01:15:02.822 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.822 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:02.822 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
01:15:02.829 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
01:15:02.831 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Could not load class for config location [/WEB-INF/webSecurityConfig.xml] - trying package scan. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/webSecurityConfig.xml
01:15:02.832 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved location pattern [classpath*:/WEB-INF/webSecurityConfig/xml/**/*.class] to resources []
01:15:02.832 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - No annotated classes found for specified class/package [/WEB-INF/webSecurityConfig.xml]
01:15:02.832 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@710f4b61: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
01:15:02.850 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.850 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.871 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
01:15:02.873 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.885 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.885 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.886 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
01:15:02.886 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.886 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.886 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.887 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
01:15:02.887 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.887 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.887 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.889 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
01:15:02.889 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.890 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
01:15:02.890 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
01:15:02.890 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
01:15:02.890 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
01:15:02.893 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@521d6601]
01:15:02.895 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@2edbf2e9]
01:15:02.899 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.u.c.s.UiApplicationContextUtils - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@a5cfc6a]
01:15:02.899 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@710f4b61: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
01:15:02.899 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.899 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.899 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.899 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
01:15:02.899 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
01:15:02.901 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@726b4ecf]
01:15:02.901 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
01:15:02.980 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletConfigInitParams]
01:15:02.980 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [servletContextInitParams]
01:15:02.980 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [jndiProperties]
01:15:02.980 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
01:15:02.981 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] not found - trying original name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].
01:15:02.981 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
01:15:02.981 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].. Returning null.
01:15:02.981 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
01:15:02.982 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
01:15:02.983 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
01:15:02.983 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
01:15:02.983 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 298 ms
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:03 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.2 (FCS 20110610) for context '/loginFormAndSpringSecurity'
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:03 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.2
01:15:04.116 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment
01:15:04.117 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:04.117 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:04.117 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:04.117 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:04.117 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
01:15:04.117 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
01:15:04.117 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy - Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5193)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/loginFormAndSpringSecurity] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
01:15:04.124 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Jun 20 01:15:02 AST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
01:15:04.125 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
01:15:04.125 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@710f4b61: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [loginFormAndSpringSecurity] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1] (value [javax.faces.context.FacesContext$1@44ea3e4d]) and a value of type [com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext] (value [com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext@3a66b65c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jun 20, 2015 1:15:04 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3907 ms
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>spring-security</display-name>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring root -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/webSecurityConfig.xml</param-value>

    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>sec_client,client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- SERVLETS -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>clientapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>clientapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

webSecurityConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="user1Pass" authorities="" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Is there further information in your log above or below this exception?

Comment: @bphilipnyc, please check the complete log in updated question

Comment: Having a similar issue with Spring Boot 2.1.1, Tomcat 9.0 and JDK 11. Any pointers will be great. I want them to work on these versions as I am upgrading my existing application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was an incompatibility between my version of Spring and the JDK. I used Spring 3.2 and JDK 1.8.  When I changed to JDK 1.7, everything worked fine.

Comment: Found this answer after 3 hours ! saved my life hah

Answer (score 0):

You need to have security configurations in root web application context. Root application context applies to the whole application. You can try with two ways -

Specify `contextAttribute` for the `DelegatingFilterProxyHave` as below -

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.
          CONTEXT.appServlet</param-value>
</init-param>
```

OR you load all configuration files in web.xml as below

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>  
           /WEB-INF/project-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/project-application-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/project-security-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/project-database-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/project-hibernate-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/project-ehcache.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: I added the init param in first section, but new error happened:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Answer (score 0):

Your webSecurityConfig.xml is probably not located in WEB-INF folder.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123516/getting-exception-no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined)

Answer (score -1):

I was facing similar problem. Then I discovered Spring app with Spring MVC has two security context. You need to define configuration for Spring context (as you doing now, by context param) and also for Spring dispatcher servlet. Define it like init-params instead of param.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
            WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```