# Problems with Oauth and spring security in a restfull application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am building a restful application with spring hiberante and mysql.

I´m trying to integrate an example of oauth2 I found on internet.
I have the controllers that the spring-security.xml asks for but I´m getting error with the startup.

I start the app with this:

Initializer .java :

```
package com.sprhib.init;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

}
```

WebAppConfig .java :

```
package com.sprhib.init;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.sprhib")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

I have this spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd ">

    <!-- @author Nagesh.Chauhan(neel4soft@gmail.com) -->
    <!-- This is default url to get a token from OAuth -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
            parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
        and what roles have access to them -->
    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>


    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password 
        combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users 
        credentials from DB -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="beingjavaguys" password="spring@java" authorities="ROLE_APP" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>


    <!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
        but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
    <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
        and other things -->
    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <!-- client -->
        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
            authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
            authorities="ROLE_APP" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

        <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
            secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_APP" />

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <sec:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
            http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</beans>
```

With this web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>
    <!-- @author Nagesh.Chauhan(neel4soft@gmail.com) -->

    <!--  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>  -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>  
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I´m getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\a.bazaldua.cerda\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\spring\WEB-INF\classes\com\sprhib\controller\AdminController.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\a.bazaldua.cerda\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\spring\WEB-INF\classes\com\sprhib\controller\AdminController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\a.bazaldua.cerda\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\spring\WEB-INF\classes\com\sprhib\controller\AdminController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:53)
    ... 24 more

oct 13, 2015 4:33:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\a.bazaldua.cerda\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\spring\WEB-INF\classes\com\sprhib\controller\AdminController.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\a.bazaldua.cerda\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\spring\WEB-INF\classes\com\sprhib\controller\AdminController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:290)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\a.bazaldua.cerda\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\spring\WEB-INF\classes\com\sprhib\controller\AdminController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:266)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:53)
    ... 24 more
```

Any ideas why the context is wrong?

Comment: what version of java and spring are you running.?

Comment: You got the point, I use java 8 with spring 3.2.9 so thats why.... so...with  that... after changing 1.7 I have this error:  No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Comment: Any ideas about that error?

Comment: there is a similar issue reported in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123516/getting-exception-no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined   Have a look

Comment: Take at look at home. thanks

Comment: I found one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526695/java-1-8-asm-classreader-failed-to-parse-class-file-probably-due-to-a-new-java

Comment: Above is exactly same issue as reported by you. I seriously feel its all about the version mismatch. Let me know how you go mate

Comment: YEAP you rule man... and so do I . I just migrate to spring 4.0  

Im getting know this error: InsufficientAuthenticationException: There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.  For the Oath token I would look for that

Comment: @AlbertPinto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130156/insufficientauthenticationexception-there-is-no-client-authentication-try-addi   I could not resolve that issue here is the question just if youre interested